# Provisioning Profiles was invalid but Certificate and App ID are valid, why is that

Tags: ios, xcode, certificate, provisioning-profile

My provisioning profile suddenly became invalid. 
I logged in developer.apple.com couples of days ago and everything was fine. Today I logged in again and was surprised to find that both of my development profile and distribution profile were invalid. The certificates and App ID are valid, I did not revoke any of them and they are not expired at all. So why my profile became invalid?

I know I can re-generate profile but because I do enterprises distribution not app store distribution. I am worried that regenerating profile may affect current users. Also, I really need to figure out the reason to prevent it from happening again.

Any idea? Thanks!

Updated: First of all, it is not because the profiles were expired, their expiration date is at the end of 2015.

Second,  I did re-generate development profile at morning but I just checked it and found the profile was invalid again! Something weird must happen and I have submitted a support ticket to apple and wait for their response.

Answer (score 9):

I'm curious to see what Apple support says.  According to Apple (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1878/_index.html) :

> Q:  What causes the provisioning profile "Invalid" status? How do I resolve it, and how do I prevent it?
>
> A: The provisioning profile invalid status is caused by changes to the profile’s associated certificate or App ID. Any time an App ID or certificate changes, all profiles that are associated to it are marked Invalid. This does not apply to Xcode's team profiles, but applies to all profiles that Xcode does not manage, specifically, custom development profiles and distribution profiles. This document explains the causes in detail and provides steps to resolve and avoid the profile invalid status.

One possibility is that you modified the app id by turning on or off services in Xcode:

> Avoidance
>
> Since Xcode started managing services on App IDs (through the Xcode >
> Target > Capabilities tab), Invalidating provisioning profiles became
> as easy as enabling or disabling a target capability. Remember that
> every time the App ID changes with respect to its enabled services,
> all profiles attached to that ID become invalid.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, I know the document you mentioned and that is why I emphasize that "Certificate and App ID are valid" in my question title.

Comment: After some inquiry they referred me another time and I am still waiting for their answer

Comment: Changing the app entitlements (e.g. turning on iCloud, or push notifications) won't invalidate an app id, but it could invalidate the provisioning profiles associated with the app id.

Comment: I think it was apple problem. They did not give me answer so far. But profile still show invalid but my app can run without problem.

Comment: Pathetic.  Some of our Provisioning Profiles include wildcards, so aren't app specific, and even those (aswell as all the rest of our Provisioning Profiles) have become invalid for some reason.

Comment: Did any of your developers connect Xcode to the developer account and try to use the "Fix issues" button?  That will often invalidate all your manually built provisioning profiles.

Comment: All I can say is "fix issues" button is not helpful at all.

Comment: No, it rarely fixes things and often breaks things.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that somebody still hits this problem after almost a year when I first raised it. So I am answering my own question trying to provide some insight.

Apple never answered my ticket instead they returned my credit. I took that as a sign that they had no idea either (saw my comments above). I can still use that "invalid" profile but it really made me uncomfortable. So I created a different one.

In summary it maybe just a bug in their system and if you have tried all the solutions and the problem still exists just create a new one.

Comment: I have had this happen repeatedly. It does not seem fully consistent, but when I add a new device to my adhoc profile, sometimes the prod profile, which has no devices tied to it, goes invalid. That's what seems to be happening, but possibly it is developers touching and then undoing changes?

Comment: "but possibly it is developers touching and then undoing changes" did you mean someone else touched the profile or you meant something else? Sorry I was confused. If you meant someone else also touched it was probably not my case. But t was several years ago when I did enterprise development so I can not be 100% sure either.

Answer (score 1):

1. If you generate a new provisioning profile, your old installations (store or adhoc) won't be affected
2. The provisioning profile lives for 1 year, maybe it expired so simply remove it and make another one with the same certificates, app ids and devices and you can use it without any problem

EDIT:

I don't know a case where a provisioing profile would become invalid unless:

1. It reached its expiry date;
2. You modified the app id or certificates that are related to it.

Comment: I updated my answer, what happened with you is strange

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's related **Automatically manage signing** in Xcode. In case you switch to another branch which has different configures in Xcode > Target > Capabilities, Xcode will change your App ID settings

Answer (score 0):

If you generate a new CSR for something like an APNS certificate, it will mark your provisioning profiles as invalid.

Answer (score 0):

Guess I found the answer, it's simple go to the apple developer account and select those certificates which wasn't working.

1.Edit them and simply add some new name just to remember.

2. Select same App Id and certificate for both development profile and distribution profile and hit the download button
3. After downloading add them into you Xcode and you will them there.

***it generally happens when you update your Xcode, so be sure when you check certification where Xcode is mentioned(For use in Xcode 11 or later in my case)***

Answer (score 0):

For me it's just opening the apple developer account, edit the profile, save it and download the provisioning. Made a new build and then reupload it.