# Invalid provisioning profile after submission

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, app-store-connect, provisioning-profile

Yesterday I submitted my application for review, the iOS Distribution provisioning profile was valid and the submission went through and the the app is now waiting for review.   This morning I have gone into the member centre and the profile used to submit the app is now showing it's status to be 'invalid'

Does anyone know why this might be and will my app be rejected because of it?

Answer (score 2):

No your app will not get rejected. You can look at this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28186088/provisioning-profiles-was-invalid-but-certificate-and-app-id-are-valid-why-is-t) for more info. You can use the same profile by just editing it.

Comment: thank you for your response, so looks like it won't be affected.  If I generate the certificate again It will not effect the app in review?

Comment: I haven't came across a situation as yours but apps that are live on the store don't get affected by re-generation of certificates. So I think app is on review will do the same.